# Planning Upgrade to Exchange 2010, but some old Exchange 2000 Information Still in AD

Tags: exchange-2010

I'm planning to upgrade my Exchange 2007 environment to Exchange 2010.  As part of my planning process, I ran the Exchange Best Practices Analyzer, and it came up with the following error:

> Server name is running Exchange 2000. This server must be
>   decommissioned or upgraded to Exchange Server 2003 before Exchange
>   Server 2010 can be installed into the organization.

The server that turned up in the scan does not exist in our environment, and as far as I can tell, the organization hasn't used Exchange 2000 for a few years.  I wasn't with the organization at the time, so I don't know if my predecessor (or the consultants he hired) decommissioned Exchange 2000 correctly.

I came across a posting in the Microsoft Technet forums that say to use ADSIEdit to delete that server from Configuration...>Services...>Microsoft Exchange..>ORG...>First Admin Group..>Administrative Group..>Servers..>

Are there any drawbacks to doing this?  Will this have any effect on mail flow?  Is there a way for me to back up that object (like backing up a registry key before making a change) before doing the delete, or do I need to do a system state backup and authoritative restore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the device is really gone, by all means, strip the old cruft objects out of AD.